# problem using footnote in the chapter title in thesis

Tags: footnotes

When I add footnote on the chapter title, all the figures in that chapter are changed their locations and stay after the text ends. Please help if you have had similar problems. I'm attaching the short form of the code.

```
\documentclass[12pt,footinclude=true]{report}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{html}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[none,dcucite,abbr]{harvard}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{uathesis}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage[textwidth=13cm,textheight=20cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage[left=4.5cm,right=4.5cm,top=4.5cm,bottom=4.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\makeglossaries\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{acknowledgement}[theorem]{Acknowledgement}
\newtheorem{algorithm}[theorem]{Algorithm}
\newtheorem{axiom}[theorem]{Axiom}
\newtheorem{case}[theorem]{Case}
\newtheorem{claim}[theorem]{Claim}
\newtheorem{conclusion}[theorem]{Conclusion}
\newtheorem{condition}[theorem]{Condition}
\newtheorem{conjecture}[theorem]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{criterion}[theorem]{Criterion}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{exercise}[theorem]{Exercise}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{notation}[theorem]{Notation}
\newtheorem{problem}[theorem]{Problem}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\newtheorem{solution}[theorem]{Solution}
\newtheorem{summary}[theorem]{Summary}
\newenvironment{proof}[1][Proof]{\textbf{#1.} }{\ \rule{0.5em}{0.5em}}
\begin{document}
\chapter[abcd]{abcd\footnote{test}}
 \label{chap:Ab}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Edit your post and use the button `{}` to format the code.

Comment: Sorry, could not understand where to edit using {}

Comment: Sorry, I don't know if you have reputation enough to edit your own posts.

Comment: I don't think the problem is related to the footnote. Are you using `\begin{figure}[!h]`?

Comment: It's hard to diagnose the problem, let alone provide a cure, since your MWE doesn't generate any `figure` environments.

Comment: @Mico Calling that an MWE is surely a misuse of language ;)!

Comment: Are you willing to add a proper MWE?